# Why Angular doesn't work when including it using Rails asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have js controller where Factory is called:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('projectAlabama')
      .controller('indexResourceListController', indexResourceListController);

  indexResourceListController.$inject = ['resourceListFactory'];

  function indexResourceListController(resourceListFactory) {
    var vm = this;

    resourceListFactory.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
      vm.lists = data.splice(0, limit);
    });
  }
})();
```

2 approaches of including angular into the project - different result.

First one: using asset pipeline

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-angular'
gem 'rails-assets-ng-resource'
```

application.js

```
//= require angular
//= require ng-resource
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-material

//= require app
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree ./controllers
//= require_tree ./factories
```

Error !

```
angular.self.js?body=1:13643 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at new indexResourceListController
```

Second approach using CDN:

layout.html.erb

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

And everything works smoothly.

Can someone explain me why ?

Comment: which gem did you use for `angular`?

Comment: @PraveshKhatri updated question

Comment: Please check after removing `//= require_tree .` and `//= require ng-resource` .................... and apply `//= require angular-resource`

Comment: @PraveshKhatri it doesn't have require_tree . It still doesn't work

Comment: @skrypalyk What is the versions being downloaded when u use the rails assets approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly feel that you might be having some versioning issue, or issue related to the ordering of your assets. I have Angular Rails which works fine just fine. The only difference is I've used bower to manage download and Install the assets I need.

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.0",
    "angular-route": "1.5.0",
    "many-more" : "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.3"
  }

}
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-rails-templates

//= require ng-app/app
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ../javascripts/ng-app
```

Please note that the order in the application.js is very important. It'd digest the file according to the mentioned order.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to do some ammends in your gem file.

```
 source 'https://rails-assets.org' 
 gem 'rails-assets-angular'
 gem "rails-assets-angular-resource"
```

and in your application.js

```
 //= require angular-resource
```

and try to remove `//= require_tree .`  I think it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Pull this require code in a seperate file and then require this file in application is. You can check your network tab in browser too see if angular is loading after or before ngresource.

Comment: Angular is required before ng-resource. Network is showing API request to the server

Answer (score 0):

Because Angular needs some tricks:

1) Avoid to use jQuery if is possible
2) Turbolinks can cause conflicts
3) If you need to use jquery, remeber to wrap the compatibility with jquery

[basic reference](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/4-lessons-learned-doing-angular-on-rails)